# Are there any specifications required for the computer which would be connected to Computer Automated Measurement and Control (CAMAC)?

Tags: nuclear-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering, experimental-technology, computer

I wanna buy a computer to use with [Computer Automated Measurement and Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Automated_Measurement_and_Control) (CAMAC).
Are there any specifications required for the computer which would be connected to CAMAC?

Comment: @hft CAMAC are modules for making measurements and data acquisition. Check this out https://www.wiener-d.com/modules/camac-modules/#:~:text=Main%20field%20of%20CAMAC%20use,86%2Dpin%20edge%20card%20connector.

Comment: By the way, @WinstonMyler, you could check for specification on the web site I sent you. There are manuals. Another thing, if you have a shop or something where you want to buy the device, normally you can ask a commercial guy for the specification.

Comment: So... How is this a physics question?

Comment: @hft Yes, some physics context in the question would be nice, but this is a physics question because the development of CAMAC was largely driven by experimental nuclear and particle physicists. Older experimental physicists (such as might be on Physics SE) may one of the best resources for figuring out how to connect CAMAC to a modern computer.  Many universities and labs (including my own) still have lots of old CAMAC modules sitting on shelves or in use in legacy experiments (e.g. in teaching labs).

Comment: You buy a Camac controller to mount in the crate, and it talks to the other things in the crate.

Comment: @DavidBailey - or NIM bin stuff. An expert in those can do some amazing things that a recent grad has no clue that it can even be done…

Comment: I wish one could cast anti-close votes. This definitely is a physics question. If folks don't know what camac is they should simply move on, but not downvote.